# How to filter the values from LazyPagingItems in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I am using paging3 to show the list of items with pagination, I wants to add search view from this page so I want to filter the values from LazyPagingItems. How to do this.

```
var values= viewModel.getvalues.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Gray)){
    var searchText = state.value.text
    if(searchText.isNotEmpty()){
      /*I want to filter the value based on search text*/
    }
    items(
        items =values,
    ){ value ->....
```

Comment: You would need to apply [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#filter-by-predicate) on your collection based on the searchText value.

Comment: Filter working in List only but filter not available in LazyPagingItems()

Comment: Have you looked at the [guide to transforming your Paging data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform) and specifically how it [does filtering](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#filter-data) at the Pager level (rather than at the UI layer, like you are trying to do, and which isn't supported)?